# How do I install AppImageLauncher in ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04

Both deb files from "https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher"

Return "Cannot satisfy dependencies"

I want to integrate app images in my system.

Comment: Your question should show us actual input and output. "*Cannot satisfy dependencies*" simply tells us the nature of the problem. It lacks the detail we need to offer solutions. It could be as simple as a typo. Or a wrong version. Or it could be complex. Lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 24):

To install AppImageLauncher on Ubuntu 21.04 (*hirsute*) add the  [AppImageLauncher - Stable PPA - Official Releases](https://launchpad.net/%7Eappimagelauncher-team/+archive/ubuntu/stable) to your system by using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appimagelauncher-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appimagelauncher
```

Comment: Just confirming this works using KDE on an Ubuntu base.  Lets you specify the install location, you can have AppImages automatically installed or ask if you want to run in situ when opened, and loads icons correctly.

Only thing I'm not sure about, as I've not tried, is having it install to `/opt` or some other root owned location.

Comment: 21.10 (impish) also there :)

Comment: Works great with `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64`.

Comment: `Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu lunar Release  404  Not Found`